# Prevent Reading and Writing to a File at the Same Time

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I have a process that needs to read and write to a file. The application has a specific order to its reads and writes and I want to preserve this order. What I would like to do is implement something that lets the first operation start and makes the second operation wait until the first is done with a first come first served like of queue to access the file. From what I have read file locking seems like it might be what I am looking for but I have not been able to find a very good example. Can anyone provide one?

Currently I am using a TextReader/Writer with .Synchronized but this is not doing what I hoped it would.

Sorry if this is a very basic question, threading gives me a headache :S

Comment: Which version of the framework? And for each unit of work will have 1 reader then 1 writer?

Comment: .NET 4.5 and yes there will be one read then one write. I'm not sure I understand the second question but the reads and writes are independent and not coupled.

Comment: Well, I'm asking if the read always come before the write?

Comment: Ah OK, yes there will always be a read before the write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be as simple as this:

```
public static readonly object LockObj = new object();

public void AnOperation()
{
    lock (LockObj)
    {
        using (var fs = File.Open("yourfile.bin"))
        {
            // do something with file
        }
    }
}

public void SomeOperation()
{
    lock (LockObj)
    {
        using (var fs = File.Open("yourfile.bin"))
        {
            // do something else with file
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, define a lock object, then whenever you need to do something with your file, make sure you get a lock using the C# `lock` keyword. On reaching the `lock` statement, execution will block indefinitely until a lock has been obtained.

There are other constructs you can use for locking, but I find the `lock` keyword to be the most straightforward.

Comment: Doesn't the lock object need to be the file stream itself?

Comment: Can be. Doesn't have to be. I used a separate `new Object()` out of habit. This allows locking on value types too.

Comment: @shortspider: if you abstract your reading/writing into a class, you could use the stream itself as the locked object.

Comment: I don't think it's smart to make the lock object the stream itself. Preferably you'd like to close ad dispose of the stream asap. Since lock operations work with memory addresses and any newly created stream will most likely be another address you would have to manage that as well. Plus, if i'm not mistaking, the guidelines push on using seperate lock objects.

Comment: Seems sensible. Guidelines actually seem to promote `lock(this)` for instance methods and `lock(typeof(ContainingClass))` for static methods. Yet `lock(lockObj)` is used all over MSDN in related examples. I go with the latter because I like the finer-grained control.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a current version of the .Net Framework, you can benefit from [`Task.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx).

If your units of work are logically always, "read some, then write some", the following expresses that intent succinctly and should scale:

```
string path = "file.dat";

// Start a reader task
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadFromFile(path));

// Continue with a writer task
task.ContinueWith(tt => WriteToFile(path));

// We're guaranteed that the read will occur before the write
// and that the write will occur once the read completes.
// We also can check the antecedent task's result (tt.Result in our
// example) for any special error logic we need.
```